# find pairwise row differences of numpy array (with perdioic boundaries)

Tags: python, numpy, pairwise-distance

I have a (N,3)-dimensional numpy array holding the 3-dim. positions of N particles in its rows. I want to obtain the pairwise distances of these particles using periodic boundaries (the latter means that if particles have a x-, y-, or z-distance d that is larger than a value L/2, then we take the distance abs(d-L) rather than d itself).

My C-like prototype looks like this:

```
def get_distances(positions, L):
    """Compute distances from positions using periodic boundaries"""
    
    rs = []
    L_half = 0.5*L
    
    for pos_i in positions:
        for pos_j in positions:
            rx = np.abs(pos_i[0] - pos_j[0])
            rx = rx if rx < L_half else np.abs(rx-L)

            ry = np.abs(pos_i[1] - pos_j[1])
            ry = ry if ry < L_half else np.abs(ry-L)

            rz = np.abs(pos_i[2] - pos_j[2])
            rz = rz if rz < L_half else np.abs(rz-L)            
        
            rs += [np.sqrt(rx*rx + ry*ry + rz*rz)]
    
    return rs
```

How can I make this more efficient and Pythonic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your provided pseudocode is correct? In particular, the line `rs += [np.sqrt(rx*rx + ry*ry + rz*rz)]` is in the outer loop, so it would only use the `rx, ry, rz` computed in the last iteration of the inner loop.

These are some numpy tricks that you might find useful for your problem:

```
import numpy as np

N, L = 10, 1
arr = np.random.rand(N, 3)

# You can use broadcasting to do an operation between
# each pair of elements within an array:
r = np.abs(arr[:, None, :] - arr[None, :, :])
# `r.shape == (N, N, 3)`; the absolute difference
# between each pair of shape (3,) subvectors in `arr`.

# if-else logic is solved using `np.where`:
s = np.where(r < L/2, r, np.abs(r - L))

# np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + ...) is done with `np.linalg.norm`:
out = np.linalg.norm(s, axis=2)
```

Which leaves you with a shape `(N, N)` array!

Comment: you were right with your comment to my code. thank you!